# 'Tensor object' has no attribute 'numpy' issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have attached the error message below. So I created a training function that is stored in another file and imported and called in the main file. I am not sure which part of the training function leads to the 'tensor object' does not have 'numpy' attribute error.

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-4ddccfd682ac> in <module>()
     23                       monitor=settings['monitor'],
     24                       epochs=settings['max_epochs'],
---> 25                       output_path=savedir
     26                       )

10 frames
/content/model.py in train_model(model, X_train, X_train_rc, y_train, binary_y, fix_len, **kwargs)
    315     else:
    316       hist = model.fit([f_seq, rc_seq], label, batch_size=batchsize, epochs=max_epochs, validation_split=0.1,
--> 317                       class_weight=class_weight,callbacks=[checkpoint,reduceLR,change_lr,earlystopping,plothis])  
    318 
    319     print( "Saving model...")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1156                 _r=1):
   1157               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1158               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1159               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1160                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
```

The error message continues on and it ultimately doesn't seem to relate to the tensor object issue. The real issue I think is related to the custom metric function I created.

```
def negative_predictive_value(y_true, y_pred):
    # negative predictive value (TN/(TN+FN))
    TN = obtain_tn(y_true, y_pred)
    TP = obtain_tp(y_true, y_pred)
    FN = obtain_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    FP = obtain_fp(y_true, y_pred)
    epsilon=0.00000001
    NPV = TN / (TN + FN + epsilon)
    return NPV
```

And one `obtain_tn(y_pred, y_true)` function looks like this:

```
def obtain_tp(y_true, y_pred):
  import tensorflow as tf
  m = tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()
  m.reset_state()
  m.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None)
  tp = m.result().numpy()
  return tp
```

I wanted to implement custom negative predictive metrics. Although the error message doesn't point to this part, I noticed after I remove these custom metrics, the code runs properly so I suspect the issue comes here.

Also, this part of the custom metrics function I learned from stack overflow and seems to work properly.

```
def F1_score(y_true, y_pred):
  # harmonic mean (balance) of precision (positive predictive) and recall (sensitivity/true positive rate)
  # 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall))
  import keras.backend as K
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1))) # TP
  possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))) # P (TP+FN)
  predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))) # TP+FP
  recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
  precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
  return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

Does anyone have insights into what is going wrong in my custom metric function? Or, does anyone have any idea on how to write a proper custom metrics function that can obtain the true positive, false positive, true negative, false negative so that I can calculate derivative measures of the confusion matrix?

Comment: Where is this error you are talking about? Your error log has nothing about tensor object!

Comment: Hi Kaveh! Sorry that I was still editing. I have provided more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `numpy()` is only supported in eager mode and what you are trying to do is to call it in graph mode.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put add the following line of code

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```